# How to Convert structure to Byte array in c#.net but the structure size defined in runtime only

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, structure, marshalling

I have a structure like below

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStructType
{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public byte stx;

public UInt16 cmdId;

public UInt16 status;

public UInt16 pktNo;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public byte contPkt;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public byte dataoffset;

public UInt16 dataLength;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 6)]
public byte[] data;

public UInt16 checkSum;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public byte cr;
}
```

i tried to convert this structure to byte array by using below code.

```
byte[] ConvertStructureToByteArray(MyStructType str)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }
```

but i got the below error while because size they dont know

> Type 'MyStructType' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

the problem because of

```
public UInt16 dataLength; 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 6)] 
public byte[] data;
```

dataLength calculated on runtime. How can i convert this structure to ByteArray?

Comment: I don't think this works in structs. Assuming you want to do this to send it to a C/C++ function, you might have to use `IntPtr` instead, and explicitly set it yourself using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and fill it using `Marshal.Copy()`

Comment: Yes i did that.. see the ConvertStructureToByteArray method.

Comment: I meant you need to declare `data` as `IntPtr`

Comment: My understanding is that `SizeParamIndex` works *for different parameters in an `extern` call*, not inside the existing type; for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

#### Limits of Marshalling

As you already noticed, `Marshal.SizeOf()` cannot compute the size of a struct containing a `byte` array with `UnmanagedType.LPArray`. However, it doesn't mean you cannot compute it by yourself.

However, even if you do so, you'll get `Marshal.StructureToPtr` complaining about data field which must use SafeArray or ByValArray.

You should check [this on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor2) in order to understand how to pass arrays from Managed to Unmanaged. However it seems that for **arrays contained in a struct**:

> The size can be set only as a constant

#### Why not using Serialization ?

Protocol Buffer is a simple way to serialize data to binary. Furthermore, it support model change, model share, and several other cool features.

It is available in several languages:

- C# API : [Protobuf-csharp-port](https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port) or [Protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)
- [Google C++ API.](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer that offers a solution, due to the limits of Marshalling as pointed out in  the answer provided by @Fab

```cs
public UInt16 dataLength; 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 6)] 
public byte[] data;
```

Marshalling doesn't actually deal with arrays very cleanly because it doesn't calculate the offsets for each element in the array as you would expect (even with the provided attributes, go figure!). Since your structure is small, you can do the following which will marshal the bytes correctly:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStructType
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public byte stx;

  public UInt16 cmdId;

  public UInt16 status;

  public UInt16 pktNo;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public byte contPkt;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public byte dataoffset;

  public UInt16 dataLength;

  public MyDataArray data;

  public UInt16 checkSum;

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
  public byte cr;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = Size)]
public struct MyDataArray
{
  public const int Size = 6;

  public byte Byte0;
  public byte Byte1;
  public byte Byte2;
  public byte Byte3;
  public byte Byte4;
  public byte Byte5;

  public MyDataArray(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes == null || bytes.Length != Size)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bytes));
    Byte0 = bytes[0];
    Byte1 = bytes[1];
    Byte2 = bytes[2];
    Byte3 = bytes[3];
    Byte4 = bytes[4];
    Byte5 = bytes[5];
  }

  public byte[] ToArray() {
    return new byte[Size] { Byte0, Byte1, Byte2, Byte3, Byte4, Byte5 };
  }
}
```